# Can Solr index sentences instead of web pages?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I've just set up Solr, indexed some pages (crawled using Nutch) and I can now search.

I now need to change it to index sentences instead of web pages. The result I need is, for example, to do a search for "one word" and get a list of all sentences that contain "one" and/or "word".

I'm new to Solr so any pointers to where I should start from to achieve this would be extremely helpful. Is it at all possible? Or is there an easy way of doing this I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Solr indexes 'documents'. You define what a document is by what you post to it via the REST-ful endpoint. If you push one sentence at a time, it indexes one sentence at a time.

If you meant, 'can I push a document, have solr split into sentences and index each one individually', then the answer is, I think, not very easily inside Solr. If you are using Nutch, I'd recommend putting the splitting into Nutch so that it presents solr with one sentence at a time.

Neither the analysis chain nor [update request processors](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor) provide for splitting a document into littler documents. You might also contemplate the Elastic Search alternative, though I have no concrete knowledge that there's a greased pole to slide down that leads to your solution there.